# How to merge duplicate questions

Tags: discussion, review-queues, specific-question, duplicate-questions, merged-questions

This close review queue has the question https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5211646 as a duplicate. The two questions are extremely similar. They are:

[Func vs. Action vs. Predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317479/func-vs-action-vs-predicate)  -- proposed for deletion, asked 2010-11-30 and having over 600 votes for both Question plus Answers. It is a favourite of 105 people.

[Delegates: Predicate Action Func](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566860/delegates-predicate-action-func) -- to be retained, asked 
2009-02-19 but having under 110 votes in total. It is a favourite of 22 people.

How should I recommend that the two questions be merged, or perhaps that the wrong one is marked for deletion?

Comment: You should flag a moderator who will merge the answers of the two questions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree that the later question was a duplicate of the earlier question, so I closed it. The older question also asked a couple of additional questions, which are not addressed in the answers to the newer question, so I don't think they should be merged.

The newer question would require 10 votes to delete, so I don't think it's in any immediate danger. (I really wish people would not delete duplicates nearly as often as they do, but it does happen sometimes.) It's also linked in the sidebars of the older question, so it should be easy to find by people who end up on the older question.

Rule of thumb: Merging should only happen when the answers to one question are a perfect match to another. If there's information missing from one set of answers, it's probably not a good merge candidate.