# What is the correct procedure for requesting that two questions be merged?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, merged-questions

There was some discussion in [SOCVR chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/conversation/discussion-how-to-request-question-merging) whether these two questions should be merged.

- [What is the difference between parseInt() and Number()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090518/string-to-int-use-parseint-or-number)
- [What is the difference between parseInt(string) and Number(string) in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564158/what-is-the-difference-between-parseintstring-and-numberstring-in-javascript)

There was a lack of clarity — do we need to post the request on Meta, or just raise a Mod flag for a merge request (as suggested here: [What is a "merged" question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158066/what-are-merged-questions))?

There is this question - [How to merge duplicate questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262495/how-to-merge-duplicate-questions). However, a recent flag requesting a merge was declined with the explanation that it needed a community vote first:

[image: screenshot of declined flag]

Comment: I've never heard of question merges. Is that a 'thing?' I was under the impression that the existing question-dup philosophy encourages google result heterogeneity, which brings more people to the site. The dup effectively acts as a signpost. Wouldn't a merge counter that effort?

Comment: Is your question a dup of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262495/656243? That questions specifically asks, "How should I recommend that the two questions be merged..."

Comment: @LynnCrumbling no, because the given procedure was not used recently, as a Mod declined a user's flag for a merge request, saying it needed to be discussed on meta first (rather than just flagging).. the comment is going to be put into the question. Thanks for finding that.

Comment: Ah, the confusion makes sense then.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling yep, it just took a while to get the question there. :)

Comment: Note that the user (me) who made the merge request that got declined holds a gold badge for the tags in question, there couldn't be a community vote.

Comment: @cimmanon - I'm curious, why didn't you vote to close as a duplicate before requesting the merge?

Comment: @BradLarson She'd have dupe-hammered it.

Comment: @BradLarson I believe it was because both questions are very highly voted so its almost a coin flip as to which one to choose from, hence the merge request.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling: There's no reason not to dupe-hammer them. For one thing, it makes the moderator aware that you are a gold badge holder, for another it is the appropriate action regardless whether the merge request will be accepted or not.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This isn't going to be a complete answer, but I did decline both of the flags mentioned above, so I can elaborate on my thoughts.

A question merge is completely irreversible, even by moderators. Therefore, we're very hesitant to use this because we can't undo a bad call.

A merge effectively combines two questions into one. All answers, comments, etc. are transferred from one question to another. Answers and comments aren't reworked or rewritten, so if there is even a slight difference between the two questions, the answers and comments merged over from the other question can seem weird or even wrong.

I've tended to only merge questions where it was clear they were identical (same user double-posted or created a new account and used that to repost their question) and where there were answers of value on both versions of a question.

If the questions aren't word-for-word replicas, I'm very reluctant to merge. This is particularly true if one question is not even closed as a duplicate of another (the case for one of the above). Moderators are rarely subject matter experts on the material involved, so we can't truly judge if something is completely identical and if all the answers and comments would indeed apply to another question if merged over to it.

For example, two of the questions you point out above are phrased:

> What is the difference between parseInt(string) and Number(string) in JavaScript?

in one and

> How do parseInt() and Number() behave differently when converting strings to numbers?

in another. Those are pretty close, but does the "when converting strings to numbers" bit in the second give it a slightly different tone than the first? I'm not confident enough to say one way or another.

If I miss a subtle difference between the two, merge them anyway, and then someone complains and points out the difference, the damage cannot be undone. I therefore err on the side of caution with merges.

Comment: This is disappointing (but completely understandable).  My first thought is to suggest merge petitions on meta (to allow multiple users to show support), but that clearly won't scale.  As long as merging is irreversible, it can't be done by the community; as long is merging is both irreversible and moderator-exclusive, it won't be done often; as long as merging is rare, developers can't justify making it reversible or community-driven.

Comment: so to answer the question, should we change policy to have a meta discussion instead of flagging for a merge request. It would make sense to have a community discussion and vote? *(about each merge request)*

Comment: Is there any advantage of *merging* questions rather than leaving them as dupes?

Comment: @BhargavRao: The answers posted to the duplicate are seen by users who only visit the canonical question.

Comment: "*does it give it a slightly different tone than the first?*" - not in my ears. These duplicates are closer than most others I have closed or requested merges for. Please merge them. I really would consider them "exact duplicates", and every answer on one is valid on the other.

Comment: @Bergi I agree that they are identical. The wording is not identical, but the question is and the answers would be the same for both.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom - This isn't the only problem we have with moderating duplicates. There also isn't a great path for someone to contest an incorrect gold badge close vote, since flagging a moderator for this doesn't work (we're generally not subject matter experts) and reopen review isn't great (almost all reviewers aren't subject matter experts and few people skip reviews). Moderators also can't do much for the people under 50 rep (who aren't able to cast a close flag because they can't comment) who flag us to close things as duplicates. There are a few holes in the duplicate-closing system.

Answer (score 9):

While Brad's concerns are valid, it also sounds like no question can ever be merged unless there's a conjunction of all the planets, which isn't necessarily the case. Here's my general rules of thumb (I can't speak for all moderators, but here's what would help me make that call)

## The community needs to duplicate close one of the questions to the other

This lets moderators see there's some agreement on the two being the same. Long closure is also helpful, because it gives people time to dispute the duplicate. It would be a good idea if you made a Meta post as well (especially if the closure is recent and you don't want to wait)

## They need to be *obviously* the same question

If you need to know a ton about the language first to know they're the same, it's probably not going to happen. A moderator has to be able to read both the questions and the answers to see for themselves that they are the same.

## A silver or gold badge making the request helps

These don't grow on trees, and it demonstrates there's some history with the tag itself. If you don't have one, you pretty much **need** a Meta post instead.

## There needs to be some content that is both unique and valuable between the two sets of answers

Two sets of answers retreading the same content will almost certainly NOT get merged. A high score for the answers is also helpful, because it does indicate some value to the community. Noting which content is helpful to merge also indicates some familiarity.

---

If you can meet all these criteria, then take a chance and mod flag the question you want the other merged into (in other words, the question that will get both answers). Include any Meta posts and other relevant details.

Comment: *"If you don't have one, you pretty much need a Meta post instead."* Or win the lottery and get a moderator who holds a silver or gold badge in the tag. Yeah... probably go with the Meta question option. :-)