# Another SO user reversed the dupe target on a pair of questions, closing the canonical of a more specific question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question, canonical

I've been using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920801/sass-manipulate-inherited-property) as a canonical for closing questions asking about manipulating inherited properties for quite a while now.

Yesterday, a [question asking about appending property values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336689/is-it-possible-to-append-css-transform-properties-using-sass) was brought to my attention, so I closed it as a duplicate of the canonical.  There was some [disagreement in chat about whether or not the questions are duplicates](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/29074?m=27577607#27577607).  Another gold-badge subject expert comes along and takes it upon himself to reverse which question was marked as a duplicate because he [liked the answer better](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/27627804#27627804).

- [Timeline of the original](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14920801/timeline)
- [Timeline of the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21336689/timeline)

Users have organically found the original to be more useful than the duplicate over the course of its entire life.  Meanwhile, the majority of the upvotes on the newer question came from yesterday in response to a spat with another answerer (who has since deleted their answer).  Most of the editing that took place on the newer question's accepted answer was *after* the question was closed as a duplicate.

Is there a good reason to have closed the broader canonical as a duplicate of the newer, more specific question?

Comment: Well, for starters, the new answer clearly needs more editing work.  It's got an incorrect answer appended to the end of a correct answer (at least according to .his own annotations).  If it's just wrong it should be removed, if not, it should be fixed so as to not be wrong.

Comment: I see that you provided a calm, reasoned response to their explanation: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/27628186#27628186

Comment: @BradLarson Well, he provided a calm reasoned response *here*.

Comment: ...So I assume *that*  isn't really your question. Are you arguing these aren't duplicates? Or rather that they should be merged as well as closed?

Comment: @Shog9 He's arguing that the older one is the better (and more generalized) question/answer, irrespective of its age.

Comment: So, after seeing Brad's link, it appears y'all have already discussed this in chat *with the moderator responsible.* Rather than play-acting that again here, maybe summarize your actual concerns for us so we can get to the point faster? I'll note also that you re-opened this question 7 hours ago, so you're clearly not asking for a redress of a wrong here; you're looking for something else... Spit it out.

Comment: @Shog9 I am entirely in favor of closing newer questions that have better phrasing/answers, but I don't feel that was the case here.  The moderator in question is not an expert in the tag in question (sass) and didn't feel the need to justify his actions any further than "I thought the newer one was better"  despite the fact that the question was already closed.

Comment: I do think the new question has a better answer than the old in that it actually demonstrates how to solve the problem rather than just noting at the bottom that you could use variables. Granted, the "Old answer" part probably should either be removed, or better integrated into the answer. I don't think the age of the question/answer is relevant when deciding which one should be the dupe target.

Comment: @KevinB Careful, more code doesn't necessarily make an answer better.  I don't know enough about the subject to say for sure about this instance, but there are certainly tons of great answers to questions that don't have (and don't need) any code.

Comment: I wasn't looking at *more* code, just the fact that it actually includes a way of fixing the problem that should work (i haven't actually tested it myself.) Both answers are good, i just see the other as being more useful.

Comment: @KevinB There are two answers on the older question, one of which demonstrates how one would go about using a variable to "solve the problem".

Comment: Very true, the newer doesn't seem to explain what is wrong, it just provides a solution. The other explains what is wrong very well, and suggests at a solution, but doesn't provide a demo (which of course isn't required.) Dunno, i think they're both good answers, I wouldn't argue either way.

Comment: @Kevin: If only the top-most answer could ever be seen, and you could find the answer with the explanantion from the answer without, and that answer without explanation added something not in any of the answers on the question with the answer with explanation, you might have a point. Maybe. Notice the number of qualifications in that statement...

Comment: why not both and merge them?

Comment: It kinda sucks to be a moderator, all of a sudden your normal SO usage as a subject expert starts to get scrutinized with a micro-lens.  The accusatory tone of this question is very problematic, there should be no need at all for moderators to dispense with their expertise and *only* act as an exception handler that mops the floor and puts out the garbage.  This guy knows [css], his profile shows his mettle.  If you have a technical dispute with him then treat him like a programmer instead of a moderator.

Comment: @HansPassant You could replace all instances of the word "moderator" in this meta question with "gold badge user" and it would be just as appropriate.  The meta question isn't about him being a mod, it's about which question should be the canonical.  There's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Well, don't troll my comment but edit the question if you think that the word "moderator" isn't relevant in the OP.

Comment: @HansPassant It's not *wrong* to use the word moderator when talking about the actions of a moderator.  It's appropriate to discuss on meta the appropriateness of closing any question when there's a dispute.  He's not being persecuted because he's a mod.  The question is about the situation, not the user, which is exactly what we want to have happen.  *You* are the one making it about the user, rather than the actual topic.

Comment: @HansPassant What part of reversing which question was closed as a duplicate is part of "mopping the floor and taking out the garbage" (especially when not everyone agrees as to which question/answer set is better)?  If the a moderator had done something similar in one of the tags you're an expert in, wouldn't you be a little miffed about it?

Comment: There is the "moderator" word again.  Can't this just be a dispute between subject experts?  Sure, other subject experts have closed questions I posted to, multiple times.  It was never a good reason for me to get pissed-off enough to start a meta discussion about it.  I'll edit this question, if you can't live with it then just roll back the edit and we'll know what it is really about.

Comment: @HansPassant In this particular case, it isn't a dispute between subject experts.  Madara wouldn't have been able to unilaterally open/close either question without having someone else modify the tags first because he lacks the gold badges to do so (the older question only has the "sass" tag, while the newer question is tagged with "sass", "css3", and "transform").

Comment: Right. So you are arguing that a moderator should forfeit a right he had *before* he became a moderator, picking a vote from the dialog, just because he was selected by other SO users to be trusted to act responsibly.  Lovely.

Comment: @HansPassant Do you think the action taken here was "acting responsibly"?  Or are you just here to pass judgment?  When I know that I have the power to cast the binding vote, I am more cautious with my votes (though I'll admit that I'm not perfect).  If I'm only half certain, I leave a comment.  I expect nothing less from a moderator (who is still a person that will make mistakes from time to time).

Comment: Of course.  *Any* SO user that tries to do something to improve the site is acting responsibly.  As opposed to the ~3.9 million SO users that never try to do anything responsible.  They also never get to be the subject of a meta post.  That you disagree about another SO user's action is par for the course, this happens *many* times every day.  Why you chose this particular user and this particular action to be the subject of this meta post is what I have a problem with.

Comment: Well, five hours later you still haven't felt it worth your time to edit this question into anything resembling a coherent question, proposition, or argument. I'm sticking a fork in it; please let me know when you've figured out what you actually want out of this. (yes, I'm using my gold-badge-privs to do this, strictly for the irony.)

Comment: @Shog9 I want some justification here as to why a non-expert is using their moderator powers to go behind the back of an expert when its not even clear that the non-expert's choice is any better than the expert's choice.

Comment: He told you in chat and again here that he thinks the other question is better. You clearly don't *believe* him, I get the impression that even if you did you don't particularly respect his opinion, and even if you believed him *and* respected him you'd still disagree... But those are all good reasons to discuss the nature of the questions, the nature of the answers, or (if it's getting late and you have places to be) the best strategy for merging the two and eliminating the whole debate. They're NOT good reasons for repeatedly asking the same question over and over again.

Comment: @Shog9 "I liked the other answer better" seemed like a rather lame response to my inquiry (hence my response in chat) and he didn't seem interested in discussing any further at the time.

Comment: Well... Do you want to debate the merits of the answers then?

Answer (score 8):

**Edit**: I really don't like the tone some of the comments here are starting to get. So I'm locking this question.

I've merged both questions, and had the one written more generally as the main. If you have something else to add on this subject, please open a new meta post.

---

I almost never think of the specific wording of the question when considering a duplicate (because questions can always be edited to be more generic, not the other way around).

The thing I consider most is the quality of the answers on both. And while your answer on the linked question is very good, the answer given to the other question was (in my eyes) better.

Even if I weren't a moderator and "just" a gold badge owner, I'd still do the exact same thing.

**Age is not a factor here**, neither is the fact that the duplicate direction was reversed. To me, what matters most is that the question with the best answer is the canonical, and the rest link to it. If you truly think that the direction should be reversed once more, work on improving and generalizing the answer given on the other question.

You still haven't convinced me that my decision was wrong (not here, nor in chat).

Comment: I don't care for what you're implying here:  "improve your answer and that question can go back to being the canonical".  So we play musical canonicals whenever the other guy edits his answer to be even better?

Comment: Honestly, the best solution here (as both myself and several others have suggested) would be to just merge the two and let voters decide, @cimmanon.

Comment: I did suggest that a while ago @Shog9 Sadly, moderators will always be targeted just for the fact that they're mods. They were chosen for a reason, even if you didn't vote for that particular mod, the majority did. So you're technically against the majority. I personally don't think any mod powers were abused, if OP had actually engaged on a more productive response other than *horseshit* I'm pretty sure Madara would've be responsive and reach a good middle point for both opinions(which probably wouldve been a merging) But then again, even if we are professionals this is still

Comment: cont... the internet, it's so easy to be aggressive and call names behind a screen, this just shows the true nature of some people, but hey every site in the internet has them, and we must deal with them. Like it or not.

Comment: @Shog9 What happened to ["we don't like doing mergers because there is no undo"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312091/what-is-the-correct-procedure-for-requesting-that-two-questions-be-merged)?

Comment: Then don't screw it up