# What to do when a high rep user answers a low-quality, off-topic or duplicate question?

Tags: discussion, reputation, fastest-gun

I've seen several situations where the OP wants to do something that has a very obvious answer, but the obvious answer is the wrong way of approaching things and has been asked before.

Then let's say that another user acknowledges that the question is a duplicate but they also post an answer in an attempt to gain reputation, complete with formatting, code snippet and image. To put the icing on the cake, the same user comments:

> Hi @OP, you there?

to get the attention of the OP.

The general wisdom is that you should avoid answering low quality questions and that in a FGITW situation, the better answer floats to the top. But how do I proceed when you see a high rep user disregarding this philosophy to gain reputation?  Answering these questions leaves the OP happy but also leaves the site with an answered low-quality question. I would expect better from a high-rep user.

How should one handle this situation when they can't downvote or comment?

Comment: Well, such behaviour is endemic on SO.  Compared with the posters with 20 accounts and office-wide voting rings, I guess it's not worth bothering with:(

Comment: I'd just flag these comments as "non-constructive"

Comment: @user5867440: That question shouldn't have been answered in the first place. It's just a problem that the OP wants a working piece of code for.

Comment: I think the fact that Bootstrap requires a certain markup structure is something that needs more attention. Not to mention the correct way of doing things. Yes OP is misguided but giving him what he wants is only going to make him dumber not smarter.

Comment: In general, questions about HTML/CSS/RegEx are too localized by default. People don't bother to create a [mcve], but dump their code or specification and request a fix, which the answerers happily provide. This doesn't increase the quality nor usefulness of the site. Such posts are very rarely findable and useful for later visitors.

Comment: Alright folks, I've cleaned up the comments here. Let's not make this about a specific user, we should be discussing how to handle these types of situations for anyone.

Comment: @MartinJames those things exist? That's just frustrating after working hard to earn rep! :( Maybe there should be an IP block for voting on posts originating from that IP.

Comment: The comment in question is clearly not very polite and should be deleted. If it happens repeatedly, the commenter should be penalized.

Comment: I think "too chatty" fits better @Magisch

Comment: @Ian: Yeah it sucks, but consider that programmers at Google, Facebook or Microsoft may visit SO from a very small number of IP addresses. When I worked at a device fingerprinting company, we had around 20K distinct devices coming from a single IP address (it was an AOL proxy server).

Comment: @EricJ. Yeah that's true... hopefully the clever guys at StackExchange have/will think of some way to deal with it. A luring part of the system falls down if people are able to cheat the rep system.

Answer (score 108):

I did not see the post, it is deleted.

My reply to all users who answer questions we know are off topic or dupes is:

If you are a high rep or regular user and well aware if a question isn't on-topic or is a dupe, there is no excuse to answer it. It just encourages people to post poor quality questions or not use a simple search to find the duplicate. It's easy to succumb to making the quick answer, I've done it.

Just resist that urge and vote accordingly and help us all to focus on the good content here, that sometimes takes longer to answer, as it takes more thought, research and effort.

The more people *[rep farm](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126987/what-is-rep-farming)*, the more this just invalidates the usefulness of rep as being a correlation of programming acuity. This will mean the site will lose credibility in the long run, as a programming resource or for career prospects.

As [Martin James](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/758133/martin-james) alludes to in [the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315936/blatant-rep-whoring#comment301543_315936) there's plenty of ways to gain rep that are not ethical. Reputation may be a meaningless number on a website to some, but it actually forms the entire basis of how the site functions, including access to moderation privileges. We all have a vested interest in protecting the reputation system of SO.

For those of us, who are likely to read this and participate with this enthusiasm and protectiveness of the site, we all strive to uphold the principles that have made SO such a great place and such an immense warehouse of programming knowledge.

So from this, my advice to anyone who sees this, use your votes. Downvote low quality questions and vote to close them. If the question ends up deleted from the site, the answer will be also. If it is deleted quickly enough, the rep gain for the user posting the answer will be reversed.

Comment: Current convention is to close, but not delete, duplicates.  In most cases the different question has similar answers which can be helpful in understanding the solution.

Comment: @Trisped yes true,  duplicates can be deleted manually, they are not automatically deleted.

Comment: @Trisped actually, -1 or less scored questions without answers are deleted, independently they are dupes or not.

Comment: @Braiam my comment is regarding "_If you are a high rep or regular user and well aware if a question isn't on-topic or is a dupe, there is no excuse to answer it._" which implies that answering questions you know to be a duplicate is inappropriate.  My goal was to say that there are reasons that a high rep user might answer a dup, and that it is not explicitly denied.

Comment: @Trisped I was actually expanding on Ms Yvette comment.

Comment: @MsYvette I just wanna say that specifically the duplicates shouldn't be deleted. Sometimes the original question has so poor title keywords (SEO problem) that a duplicate serves as a redirection.

Comment: @TomášZato  Sure a few dupes are ok I agree with you on search results and it gives us more answers, but it has to be reasonable.  there's sometimes a surplus of duplicates and it does get to a point, how many for eg null pointer exception questions do we want? also some duplicates are pretty low quality. But more importantly, why reward people for failing to do a simple google search?

Comment: @MsYvette What about rewarding for at least posting a good title when failing with that search. In my top 10 most viewed questions, two are duplicates. I failed to search and used a title that has much better wording than the old version. Of course, those of my questions weren't also of the low quality - but that's another topic, unrelated to the duplicate issue. Any question can be of low quality.

Comment: @TomášZato yeh true, I've had that happen when searching also. But it does become self limiting.. and if the dupe targets are hard to find, then they're maybe not the ideal.. as the dupe target should be the best Q&A collection, not necessarily the oldest.. and also existing questions can be edited to improve titles..

Comment: I do not see how reputation correlates to ability, nor how making it do so would even be helpful. Questions/answers are judged by quality. Rep, on the other hand, most closely correlates with the join date and historical activity. Correlating with ability would require a massive releveling. No, rep motivates by encouraging quality answers and questions, and providing feedback on how to improve. It is supposed to reward desired behaviors and discourage bad ones. So we get what we want, regardless of the ability of the people involved. If not, no non-pro would be here, and the site would suffer.

Comment: Not that we shouldn't try to deal with repwhores. I  just disagree that the issue is correlation with ability. It is being rewarded for undesirable behavior. The solution is, therefore, to remove this reward. Answering bad questions should be allowed, but not give rep, or at least have it refunded. It works far better to use the gamification than to depend on the community. There is no rep increase for doing a good job with these moderating tasks, so you're just counting on people having the same values. (I don't. I'm here to help people, and the site getting better is a happy side effect.)

Comment: @trlkly Whether we like it or not, SO rep is rather a valued commodity, or there wouldn't such issues surrounding it. For one it does impress many people, my last employer thought I should add SO to my CV. It doesn't take much effort to click on someone's profile and see the join date and work out how quickly they've accumulated rep, so the join date is not much of an issue. I do think it is a novel idea to remove rep gain on answers to questions with a negative score, except that would cause people to upvote bad question.

Comment: @YvetteColomb maybe a better solution is something like "answers to questions closed as off-topic/too broad/etc give no rep, and answers to closed dups are moved to the dupe target with votes reset at time of closing". The problem is then if close but not quite identical questions get closed as dupes and the answers don't apply... not an easy problem.

Comment: @mbrig automatically applying answers to the dupe target [is tricky](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312091/what-is-the-correct-procedure-for-requesting-that-two-questions-be-merged) - particularly if the question is reopened, i.e. not a dupe. Resetting votes is also [problematic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316564/remove-the-incentive-for-fgitw-to-answer-well-known-dupes).

Comment: @YvetteColomb yeah, I think dupes are a hard problem, and my solution is more a dream than something practical. The first part (no rep for answers to Qs that get closed) is possibly more practical.

Comment: @mbrig yeh I've made that suggestion somewhere on meta - I'd have to find it

Comment: @YvetteColomb good answer. I'd edit the "rep w***" thing out, since it's not acceptable anymore in SE terms.

Comment: Why should I loose -1 reputation for letting a user (who sometimes has 10 times more reputation than me), know that his answer was inappropriate, which will make him loose 2 reputation points, when his inappropriate (upvoted and accepted) answer bring him +25?

Answer (score 1):

I'm all for closing low quality questions, but you have to admit that such a thing isn't very well defined despite it being very obvious sometimes. I think that to some extent "lowish quality" questions being ansered is okay, despite the karma whoring, because in the end someone is being helped. Obviously repeat questions or questions that are "fix my code for me" don't help anyone but the asker and the guy who gets karma for answering, my point is that sometimes veteran users are a bit callous towards new users.

For example, one of my questions on the gaming stackexchange ("can you drop bottlecaps in fallout?") got absolutely *nuked* as soon as I posted it, because people who didn't play the game said the question *looked* like I never tried to solve the problem myself at all. So this attitude of only answering "good" questions and marking anyone who answers the rest as "repwhores" is not really fair and in the long run will result in more and more questions getting the same treatment mine did.

By the way, as soon as I explained that I indeed was *not* shitposting, I got a super interesting answer (make a bottlecap mine and detonate it, and collect the resulting bottlecap shrapnel). I like to think that it's worth it to answer somewhat bad questions (or questions that may *seem* bad) than it is to try to punish users into behaving "correctly" by deleting questions to prevent repwhores from potentially giving good answers.

Comment: This answer assumes the terrible question can still provide a valuable answer, which usually isn't the case when it comes to "obvious Q/As" as the OP is describing. Sure there are some terrible, terrible questions due to formatting/lack of MCVE/etc. that have some incredibly insightful answers, but I wouldn't label those answerers repwhores in the first place.

Comment: I hear you, but SO has a lot of questions and in the case of experienced users, particularly those who are actively involved in voting off topic questions, they shouldn't be answering them. There are some gray areas, true. But the longer people are around on here the more knowledge they have about what is acceptable and what isn't and what is duplicated. I do not support pile on, where people get massive downvotes and comments. That is just overwhelming and fails to educate any one. Remember, though,  it's not a support site to help everyone, it's a site to help those who help themselves.

Comment: I was a bit angry when I came to my question and all I had were downvotes and people telling me to go play the game. It just seemed like there were a few users out there who *thought* they were experienced users and who *thought* they were capable of drive-by judging.

Comment: (missed the edit time limit) I support curating and the culling of trash, I just don't support harsh measures to be easily available to get rid of "low quality askers and rep whores", because users quickly think they're qualified to bulk judge questions and in fact already do so. Saying "qualities A and B guarantee this should be marked for downvote & deletion" sounds right, and it would be, if people didn't keep on changing around what A and B means to suit their mood.

Comment: Your [Arqade](http://www.gaming.stackexchange.com) experience is a variant of "How do I do this?" *comment* "Well look it up yourself, and here is a downvote for not doing your research" *reply* "But I DID research first!" In other words, how could we know you did a fair amount of research if you didn't say so? (Building on that, "i typed in to google & did not get my valuable answrz" is not the kind of research SO expects.)

Comment: When the question was new, I got two or three downvotes and then after that a comment telling me to do my homework. What is actually an interesting question, because I knew that if it was even possible, it wasn't straightforward at all, was judged harshly by people who don't know that caps *aren't* an inventory object and therefore have no "drop" button. This is like someone asking a question about some weird css side effect on a certain browser and having a guy who has only ever touched c think "well that's probably in the man page, -1 no comment". Must we be completely rid of goodwill?

Comment: Just checked out [that specific question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/244922) and I am sorry to say it's actually a poster child for what I said above. Even the small addition of what you now say here ("they aren't a regular inventory item") could have been enough.

Comment: @Jongware I disagree completely. The information you're suggesting adding would already be known to anyone searching for the question or considering answering it; question askers shouldn't dump redundant info into their question just to reassure hypothetical users *completely unfamiliar with the tag* that the question is reasonable. It's not even clear what the exhortation to "try it" means in the comments on the bottlecaps question; how do you try something in a game that there's no obvious UI for?

Comment: @MarkAmery: a question that does not mention any attempt usually elicits a comment "what have you tried so far?" "How do I do *x* in language *y*?", where in the following discussion it is revealed the OP does not know *anything* about *y* ... or is a professor teaching programming. We can't know unless one tells.

Comment: @Jongware there are many questions about trivial operations that are still a good fit for stack overflow, such as jquery operations. I've seen very many of them because darn it, I've searched for them, and I was glad I didn't have to ask myself. It is 100% true that questions that try to make up for OP's lack of absolutely any knowledge or will to research, or because they're of the type "please write my code for me". But the point of my arqade question is this: it went from being a *terrible* question from a user misusing the site to an *interesting* question, without changing the text AT ALL

Comment: @Jongware on the flipside, would it help if I asked for help with printing "hello world" in C if I also added "I tried and failed" to the end of the question? Is that really what we're going to use to measure the worthiness of a question?

Comment: @leinaD_natipaC Asking that question is in and of itself evidence of insufficient research, and just saying you did research is useless fluff and lowers the posts quality, if that is at all possible.

Answer (score -12):

I do not subscribe to the "general approach" of not helping @ops who ask "low-quality" or "duplicate" questions. These metrics are entirely too subjective to be used to deny help to those who need assistance. I am not here to accumulate rep. I participate to help those who are less skilled or less experienced at this trade than they would like to be, and wish to improve. I enjoy sharing my experience and knowledge with those who can benefit from it. I am well past the point where I care what rep I have. I answer questions with a comment if the answer can be fit into a comment. I do not care that a comment does not generate rep.

If SO wishes to solve this "problem", of diluting rep for those who care about it (and I agree with @triply above, who points out astutely that rep is more an indicator of length of participation than of skill or talent), perhaps it should simply change the rules so that rep is assigned based on some subjective quality/originality of the question, as judged by those of us with appropriate level of participation/ (rep?). i.e. allow those with some threshold of rep to mark a question as "low quality" or duplicate, and once a sufficient number of SO users have marked the question as such, answering it would no longer generate rep. BUT DO NOT INHIBIT US FROM ANSWERING IT. 
Then, if we are also concerned about the clutter, for these questions determined to be duplicates or "low-quality", once the @op has marked an answer as the correct answer, after some suitable interval, delete the question from the site.

Comment: I agree that as long as a question remains open, users should be able to contribute answers to it. But...please don't post answers as comments just because you don't care about reputation. That just makes all sorts of things more difficult. If you want to prevent reputation gain for an answer, you can mark it as "community wiki" when you submit it by clicking the checkbox.