# Why do people post spam on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, spam

This is something that I do not understand at all because the community tends to respond to spam extremely fast from what I have seen.  It gets downvoted to oblivion and I can't see it staying on the site long enough for anyone to actually get a chance to click on their links.

However, I keep on seeing new instances of spam almost every day if I am doing reviews in Triage. A lot of them is the system testing if I am paying attention, but somebody still has to keep posting spam like this for the system to pick it and use that to test me with, right?

Also, I am talking about posts that are *clearly* spam, not cleverly or not-so-cleverly disguised spam. Those I can still understand the rationale. However, posting links to their "*new essay writing service*" on a site that is notorious for being rigorously strict about what they allow has to be an obviously bad idea, right?

Comment: Why do people post it anywhere; it's spam. The point of it is the post it anywhere, it doesn't matter what the real intent of the resource is.

Comment: Because they want to promote products or services without having to pay for advertising.

Comment: If there are spam bots then they don't care what is posted and if you're paid $0,001 per spam post you don't care either.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332633/beyond-flagging-it-what-can-i-do-to-stop-spam

Comment: Spammers/scammers tend to not be the most intelligent persons, there are plenty of hilarious YouTube videos exploiting that fact. Why do they do stuff? Because they think it might make them money.

Comment: Perhaps see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332634/874188 which has some speculations about the underlying economy.  ... Oh, I see @rene already linked to that.

Comment: ...because it's there.

Comment: It's logical and obvious to you. Not to a ungraduated poor guy whos job is to post given ad text into as many resources as he can. There are worser jobs though, e.g. armpit sniffers.

Comment: "obviously bad idea"—Not bad for the spammer though. Bad for the site, but what does the spammer care about that? Even if only 10 people see the spam before it's deleted, that's 10 people you got to with your spam.

Comment: Why does a bear defecate in a forested area?

Comment: You're expecting these folks to be reasonable.  That's a reach.  I was once contacted by "Microsoft Technical Support" -- *three times in one day.*  The third time, I decided to keep them on the phone and waste as much of their time as I could.  The guy got mad and said I was stealing his livelihood.  How's that for irony?

Comment: Why are there stupid people in the world? There's always those who think that if something is criminal, it is automatically profitable. Imagine if they spent the same time & effort on legal telemarketing or whatever. They'd likely make ten times the cash.

Comment: I believe that it has more to do with the Servants of Cthulhu attempting the Infinite Monkeys theorem. Post enough random crap to the Internet and sooner or later they will find the right combination and awaken the Elder Gods.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is closed with "*This question does not appear to be about Stack Overflow or the software that powers the Stack Exchange ...*". I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: "It's one spam post, Michael. What could it cost? Ten dollars?" What do you think it costs? I think it costs about $0.00. So why not?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Why do people post Spam on Stack Overflow?

To earn a living. That is the sad story. Working in the *advertising business* is not a recommendation on your CV.

> A lot of them is the system testing if I am paying attention, but somebody still has to keep posting spam like this for the system to pick it and use that to test me with right?

Yes, there is no lack of fresh posts about "amazing" products/services/scams.

> [...] has to be an obviously bad idea right?

Right. Once a post gets deleted due to spam flags, the IP address goes into SpamRam. That is the internal SE system that blocks network access for spammers. But it is an up-hill battle as it is notoriously easy to evade IP blocks.

Do know that with both SpamRam and community run efforts like [SmokeDetector](https://charcoal-se.org/smokey/) we do keep spam at bay on the SE network. So keep flagging.

Comment: Does Stack Overflow do shadowbanning?

Comment: @user253751 not that I know of nor that I have heard anyone mentioning it by either staff or long-time members.