# Roomba delete questions closed very long time ago for off-topic reasons

Tags: discussion, feature-request, clean-up, automatic-deletion

Active cleaners have the feelings that our scarce<sup>[1]</sup> deletion votes should be used for what [Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) can't handle. So my suggestion is for Roomba to help us more:

I suggest Roomba should **automatically delete off-topic posts closed for more than one year and without historical lock**.

That is:

- off-topic means it's not a duplicate, it clearly doesn't belong to the site
- closed for more than a year means that everybody had plenty of time to vote for re-opening if needed
- historical exceptions can be made with a moderator lock
- question score and top-answer score are less than 5 to avoid impacting very popular stuff

---

Thanks to @Makyen, I understand there is a current job `RemoveAbandonedQuestions` with this definition:

> If the question is more than 365 days old, and ...
>
> - has a score of 0 or less, or a score of 1 and a deleted owner
> - has no answers
> - is not locked
> - has view count <= the age of the question in days times 1.5
> - has 1 or 0 comments
> - isn't on a meta site
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted. These are termed "abandoned" questions (RemoveAbandonedQuestions).

So my proposal is equivalent to an additional job, let's call it `RemoveOldOffTopicQuestions`, that apply to:

- is closed for off-topic reason (not a duplicate)
- the closure date is more than 365 days old
- question score and top-answer score are not very high (less than 5)
- number of answers is irrelevant
- number of comments is irrelevant
- is not locked
- isn't on a meta site

I'm not sure about the view count.

[This search is an approximation of the list of impacted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ayes+duplicate%3Ano+locked%3Ano+score%3A...4+lastactive%3A..1y)

---

<sup>[1]: At 10,000 reputation, you can cast 5 delete votes per day. An additional vote is granted per 1000 reputation, to a maximum of 30 delete votes per day. ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools))</sup>

<sup>Note: We are talking about soft-deletion here, so the posts still exist and the owners can still recover the content of it. Undeletion can also be voted.</sup>

Comment: To be clear, are you referring to deleting posts closed as off-topic *regardless of whether they are upvoted, have answers, or have postively-scored or accepted answers*?

Comment: Given that there is a Roomba task, `RemoveAbandonedClosed`, which deletes some closed questions, you should explicitly state what the change is in the criteria required (i.e. show the contrast between what exists now and what you are proposing). It would be good for you to also show how many questions this impacts. I'd also recommend that you link to [the page that describes Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba).

Comment: How about posts that should stay, should stay closed and should stay unlocked? I can't think of an example unfortunately, as the C++ book list is locked and Joel's political rant was being forced open.

Comment: @JohnDvorak you're describing some weird concept: I'm not aware of something that should "stay closed as off-topic, unlocked and undeleted". But you could workaround the roomba by unclosing/reclosing it.

Comment: While I agree with expanding the criteria for Roomba (to an extent), I don't feel that having a new task which is (Closed && >365 days old && !Locked) is appropriate. There are a number of moderate/high scoring questions with well upvoted answers that contain useful information. I would be surprised if most of these have historical locks. IMO, Roomba shouldn't be used for cases where there's the potential to be deleting useful information. I might be for this if you had some limitations on what you were expanding the criteria to be (WAG: a criteria that combined score on Q&A < (#A + 5?)).

Comment: @Cœur, [This search is an approximation of the questions you are proposing to delete with this new Roomba task (with question score < 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aquestion%20closed%3ayes%20duplicate%3ano%20locked%3ano%20score%3a..9). Note: I have not limited these to any particular activity date, because by the nature of your request 99.99% (% assumed) of such questions which have been closed for > 2 weeks will reach the closed for 365 days criteria.

Comment: I think it should also apply to "too broad", "unclear what you're asking" and "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: "question **and top-voted answer** score is less than **5**" - fix that for you. Note that, based on questions alone, less than 5% of these posts have a score between 5 and 10. (Also considering answer score might reduce the number of matched questions by a lot - people upvote useless answers on useless questions a lot all the time, although the chances of accidentally deleting something useful is reduced - I wouldn't be quick to auto-delete a low-score question with a high-score answer).

Comment: @Dukeling adjustment done. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I [expressed my view in the past about "low quality" and deleting content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356511/214671), which IMO should be done only in extreme cases, *especially* given that what is on- and off-topic is costantly shifting.

There's nothing more infuriating than seeing content that you worked on being destroyed two years after the fact because someone suddenly decided that it's now off-topic, marked the question as such and then deleted it. Of course I'm all against the second step being done automatically by a trigger-happy bot.

For these reasons, these criteria

> - question score is not very high (less than 10)
> - number of answers is irrelevant

are absolutely unacceptable.

Automatic deletion should be reserved for *extremely, unambiguously bad questions*, and deleting content that has been decently well received (your run-of-the-mill decent question does *not* attract more than a handful of upvotes, especially in niche tags) and has attracted answers (so, other people spent time trying to answer it) is a no-go. The `RemoveAbandonedQuestions` triggers are already trigger-happy enough (personally, I'd have an even more conservative "badness threshold", e.g. at least -2 of score).

Comment: I would object to "answer score is irrelevant", but number of answers does indeed seem somewhat irrelevant - if the answers couldn't manage to gather at least a few upvotes over the course of a year, it's hard to argue that they add much value to the internet (even if they add *some* value, we decided the question, and thus answers as well, doesn't belong here - hanging on to everything that might potentially add some value regardless of whether it's actually in line with our rules is a bad precedent).

Comment: @Dukeling: I understand your point, a rough metric that accounts for that could be "number of answers with a positive score".

Comment: *"There's nothing more infuriating than seeing content that you worked on being destroyed two years after the fact because someone suddenly decided that it's now off-topic"* I'm not sure how generally this statement actually applies. I, for one, am not at all that attached to my answers; if some are not or no longer useful, just cast them out. Shouldn't we focus more on trying to determine what Q/As we actually want to show to the folks looking for information? At least when looking for dupe targets, the sea of "interactive debugging" relicts to wade through is rather annoying.

Comment: Thank you, as suggested by Dukeling, I've adjusted the max-score to 5 for both question and answers to partially address this concern. Note that if your question is closed, you can vote to re-open it.

Comment: @Cœur: I'm not out there patrolling all the questions I've ever replied to; this generally happens months or years after the Q/A took place.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, due to how many questions that are "off-topic" that I've seen to be useful that aren't locked (mostly because they are not popular questions), I can't agree with this.

I can't think of any specific examples off the top of my head at the moment, but a large and significant minority of questions that I come across from Google are closed (whether it be for "off topic" or another reason).

**Even if** these questions aren't great or shining examples of research, detail, accuracy, objectivity, or ability level, they can (and often are!) still useful to myself and others.

Comment: This kind of sounds like "yeah they broke the rules, but they ended up doing good so it's ok" which just opens the flood gates for more rule breaking. Off topic means it's not appropriate here -- if it's useful, it should be moved to a more appropriate venue so others can still benefit, or sufficiently rejiggered (possibly as a new QA) to be on-topic.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I would rather have a few bad questions still exist if it means questions that don't break rules (or are very minor infractions) can still exist on the site and be useful to future visitors.

Comment: Definitely +1; as I said in the past, stop deleting useful content just because, especially given that what is on- and off-topic is a constantly shifting. At very least, don't delete questions *with answers* that are (now) off-topic. It's infuriating seeing content that you worked on being destroyed two years after the fact because someone had to appease his OCD and first mark the question as off-topic and then have it automatically deleted.

Comment: @MatteoItalia closure is the first step to deletion, except in the case of good sign posts. If there is content which you find useful that is off-topic, you should find a proper venue for it. If it isn't on-topic here, it isn't on-topic. Plain and simple. Whether or not content may or may not be on-topic at some point in the future, or whether it has or has not been on-topic in the past should have no effect on whether or not a question is closed or deleted, unless it is truly historically relevant, in which case it should have a historical lock.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: This "opens the floodgates" argument keeps getting used. Occasionally someone does cite an old interesting but off-topic post as a reason their question should stay open, but nobody accepts that as valid justification for a new bad question, especially if it's also off topic.  Anyway, that's definitely the exception, and **the floodgates are already** open to crap from users that don't even read the rules at all.  We're still totally free to downvote new stuff regardless of any "precedent" arguments anyone might make, the argument isn't for going farther down that slope.

Comment: @JustinKrejcha If it just was *"a few bad questions"*, everything would be fine. The problem I see repeatedly while looking for good dupe targets is that the vast majority of questions that get washed up in the relevant searches a bad, to the point the actual good and useful questions are hard to find.

Comment: @BaummitAugen This doesn't solve that. In theory, better searching would. Very few people read 30 questions, says, "oh wow, my question sucks", and then doesn't post it because of deleting of upvoted content. *They just ask their question.* What SO is *is* obvious, but the nuance does change from time to time. The usefulness of questions is still there, in my opinion. This is also not to say of **incorrectly closed questions**, which is also staggeringly high from my experience on SO.

Comment: *"This doesn't solve that."* Not on its own, but given old garbage is a significant part of the garbage, it would be a significant step in the right direction. Preventing new garbage of course also is important, but that's discussed elsewhere. Considering incorrectly closed questions: I don't feel like there's a lot of those, esp by the "closed very long" criterion discussed here. Do you have numbers on that? (And for the "better searching" part, you go tell google to better tailor their search algorithm to SO. ;) )

Comment: I don't have any specific data points, but I've noticed that a large minority of questions that I happen upon from Google when searching for issues in response are closed. It also happens often enough to be a meme on some other programming forums. I don't see how deleting off-topic questions would make finding dupe targets easier.

Comment: *"I don't see how deleting off-topic questions would make finding dupe targets easier."* It's easier as I don't have to click on 20 code dumps before I find the one that has an MCVE and good answers. That's not restricted to dupe-finding either, it also applies to my every day work.