# Asking questions is getting more difficult day by day

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have been using Stack Overflow for more than a decade, and I'm still trying to use it. But now, people tend to either close or downvote a question as soon as it is asked. This is really frustrating.

It is not a duplicate at all. Someone said it was a typo in the code, and that's exactly the reason I have asked; I was not able to check and notice the typo.

Some say it is too subjective. By that logic, everything is subjective, but here we are asking for at least one solution.

See my last 2 questions:

1. [what is yaml syntax variations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77974491/what-is-yaml-syntax-variations)
2. [Difference of tsconfig lib value using lowercase or uppercase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77955801/tsconfig-lib-value-lowercase-or-uppercase)

Both are valid questions, but Stack Overflow users cannot chill. They do not want anyone to ask.

Do we stop asking questions?

Comment: "_I wa not able to check and notice the typo_", "_difficulat_" etc..., fouff...!, can't you spellcheck your Posts?, this one and your Qt about 'yaml' and 'github' are full-full-full of typos, this is unreadable...!

Comment: _"Do we stop asking questions ?"_ - if you can't take the effort to even minimally proofread your questions _or the code leading to them_, yes. _"what is yaml syntax variations?"_ is more than  adequately covered by the resource you reference _in the question_ but couldn't be bothered to read, for example; why expect people to spend _another_ Y minutes teaching you X?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are questions really getting worse?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362967/are-questions-really-getting-worse) which is covers why (apparently) "fewer and fewer questions are getting positive score".

Comment: "_How many typo? Full full_" => 20 already in this current Qt (Question), minus 8 corrected already by @rene, => still 12 left... (And I probably missed a few...)

Comment: It is not the reader's responsibility to correct _your_ mistakes _you_ made by putting too little effort into writing the question.

Comment: When we ask a question, it is not a single way question, it can lead to other information also. Why would I ask 2 questions which are totally related. Earlier we use to ask such a way

Comment: TS config questions being closed. Stackoverflow meant to ask questions not to harass someone .

Comment: Look, if you;re not interested in our feedback, and only want to complain about your questions getting closed, you're in the wrong place here. We identified a very clear issue with your questions. One that's easy to fix with a _little_ bit of effort from your side. If you don't want to do that, that's up to you, but then you shouldn't complain about that being a problem.

Comment: "*if there are typo, people can help to fix the typo not just close because they dont like it.*": What makes you think that the reason people vote to close your questions is that they don't like them? I voted to close the YAML question since it is unlikely to be useful to many (otherwise known as typo/unreproducible), but I neither like nor dislike it: it is but yet another question I come across while checking the feed. I can imagine other people doing the same.

Comment: @xkeshav Remember, you can vote to reopen your own questions. Generally, it would be a great idea to perform some editing to try to improve the question to address the close reasons (even if the question was closed by error, it's better to imagine there could be issues in the question that could lead other users into the same error). But if other users have already edited your question and voted to reopen, nothing stops you from casting another reopen vote yourself, if you believe it shouldn't be closed.

Comment: *"I was not able to check and notice the typo."* If you're not able to do the work, perhaps because you don't have time (?), don't dump it on other people to do; we (the community) expect you to put the time and effort in *first* before you ask. *"Some one said it is typo in code, and that's exactly the reason why I have asked"* closing a question due to it being a typographical error is a reason to close; such errors are unlikely to be helpful to future users. *"Both are valid questions"* this can't be true if the problem was a typographical error; your question here contradicts itself.

Comment: **Please also read:** [Advice for non-native English speakers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362)

Comment: So typo error are not an error? typo and syntax error are closeby. How that make questions invalid? if someone said me its typo then its resolved. So problem was there whether is is typo/semantics/syntactical in code because I am writing that code and not aware is a typo

Comment: I didnt write YAML earlier so tried whatever been there on github action docs and there are 2 3 variation of github action page itself and they recommend to read an article which is too broad and also not able to help in any manner. So asked

Comment: @xkeshav - You expect the community to fix your typos and I guess find it unreasonable for the community to expect you to fix your own typos? Part of the reason the question is closed is to give you an opportunity to fix those typos. A programming error caused by a typo in the code is a close reason.

Comment: I don't see any issue with the current state of the second question but I can see there was a concerted effort applied by several curators to improve it. You should take note of the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77955801/revisions) to see what was changed and why

Comment: Re *"I have been using Stack Overflow for more than a decade"*: Then perhaps it is time to start spelling the tech words correctly. ([I cover many of them](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=git%20hub).).

Comment: Given a better/preferred question with two options, and if I know what the <expletive deleted> I was talking about in YAML, I'd answer is with a list of pros and cons. If the asker wanted better/preferred and didn't narrow down the options, that would get the chop.

Comment: wow 34 downvote. :)

Comment: so whole point is that it's grammer mistake and people feel empowered to become grammer nazi and do downvote but not doing any help to improve and no technical ascpects are in consideration from the question itself while primary motive was stack overflow if to get technical help . this is really sad. Please stop giving lecture on how one should write. Thanks but no thanks. ( hope this is correctly written and taken by all great people here ). Thanks for grammarly and other options.

Answer (score 14):

I think most of the problem here is your failure to proofread your questions.

Take the Yaml one:

[image]

There isn't a single line in there without mistakes.
For your own benefit, I'd ***strongly*** suggest you enable *and listen to* your browser's spelling checker, or better yet, install a plugin like Grammarly to help you out.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I am not a frequent english speaker so these silly mistakes occur to happen and people can edit the question rather than downvote it. Isn't this a good way

Comment: It's not _their_ responsibility. It's _yours_.

Comment: ... No. If _you_ post a low quality question, then the close-votes are a signal _to you_ that _you_ need to improve the question. You can't _expect_ users to put time and effort into fixing _your_ mistakes when you haven't taken that time, yourself.

Comment: @xkeshav Yes, silly mistakes happen to all of us, but hardly at a rate of several per line of written text. You've been actively participating on an English-only site for almost 15 years, having made **over 1500 posts** in that time. And (to pick just one glaring aspect), in all that time you've yet to notice that English sentences begin with a capital letter? Sorry, but to me (and I'm not a native English speaker either) that just screams of laziness. Mixed with a good dose of arrogance, by expecting an army of volunteers to be constantly cleaning up after you.

Comment: I would disagree that the YAML question was closed due to the typos in the question text. It was closed due to the typos in the YAML, which then triggered the OP to ask what the syntax of YAML is, which is too broad, and is answered by the YAML specification. Sure typos in question text are annoying, but in and of itself not a reason to close a question, but to _edit_ them into shape, or nudge the OP in the comments to do it (unless of course the typos and grammar are so atrocious it is unintelligible).

Comment: When your English is as broken as you demonstrate in the original version of your question, @xkeshav , it can make it very difficult to understand intent too. We don't expect perfection (as a native speaker I make errors *all* the time) but we expect *some* effort. If your text is hard to understand as a native speaker, imagine what it's like for someone else that isn't. Putting in that minimal effort will help you correctly express intent, demonstrate you put time (and effort) into writing your content, and not be a blocker for others who can't understand a word of what your wrote.

Comment: I completely agree and understand your intent. but understand the mental state of a person who is asking the question. before asking the question I have done so much trial so there are 2 3 things going on the mind and we are not sure about anything so types as soon as possible, yes we have to keep write good language and code to show but sometimes you just need to know the syntax not exactly a logic of some typo.

Comment: @xkeshav: what kind of "mental state" will statements like, "*...but Stack Overflow users cannot chill...*" stimulate in Stack Overflow users who read your meta post? If your goal is inflame and anger members of the site (likely none of whom closed your questions), then this might succeed. If on the other hand, your goal is to encourage an objective, even and balanced discussion, then this is not the way. Please understand that the words that you choose and that you use matter.

Comment: _"Mental state"_ doesn't prevent you from using a spell-checker! That's just pure laziness. Even if you'd ___only___ install something like Grammarly, it would already ___automatically___ fix a lot of your mistakes. You keep on making excuse after excuse... None of that matters. There's a ___big glaring___ problem with your questions that you seem utterly and completely unwilling to do ___anything___ about...

Comment: Most of [the articles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Dax90QyXgI&t=17m54s) [are also](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Dax90QyXgI&t=19m05s) missing.

Comment: *"understand the mental state of a person who is asking the question."* The "mental state" of the user shouldn't matter, but anyone posting *should* be in a calm and open minded mental state, and be ready to answer responses they get promptly after posting. Any other mental state, such as angry or stressed, is unlikely to yield a good experience, @xkeshav .