# Copying Answers and indicate it

Tags: discussion

I searched for [copying answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=copying%20answer) and read a few hits but they do not seem to match.

In this case

- [What is APO? How to use it (242177)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242177/what-is-aspect-oriented-programming) was asked on Oct 28 2008
- On Nov 26 2008 it was duplicated by a similar question [What is AOP? describe it in layman’s terms (319639)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319639/).

Someone copied answers from the duplicate (younger) question (639) to the "original" / older question (177) and marked "his answers" as copies.

I edited this [copied answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/319745/819887) to include a link to the original answer and to the original author. But after consideration the whole copying answers stuff seems wrong.

- Why not delete the copied answers and link them as a comment?
- How would you handle this?

Comment: Isn't there a way (for mods) to merge the answers?

Comment: It's from 8 years ago, and they're all marked community wiki.  Yeah, add attribution, but other than that it doesn't seem like a problem in this case.  Mods *could* merge the two.

Comment: @Laurel Yes there is. It is called: merging. But I guess that didn't existed back in 2008 so that was maybe a common thing to do idk.

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312091/what-is-the-correct-procedure-for-requesting-that-two-questions-be-merged

Comment: @Laurel Thanks for the link. To quote `If the questions aren't word-for-word replicas, I'm very reluctant to merge.` because they may have subtle differences. So based on this a deletion of the copied answers would be enough and a backlink from the original to the duplicate question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This was clearly an attempt by paxdiablo (who is a very respectable user I would add) to use the current feature set from 2008 to facilitate a feature which did not exist at the time.

I would leave the whole thing alone, it is from 2008 and hasn't caused any harm this whole time.

Do not use this as an example to copy answers, or as the basis of inference. Things were different in 2008 than today in 2016.

Comment: If a user changes his answer the copy is less valuable. If the user changes his user name the given credit may not be matched. Harm is a strong word; i see it as not usefull to have a copy and therefore believe that to remove the copied answer is better.

Comment: In general, what is shown here is bad practice and if you find a recent example it should be removed. In this exact scenario, I think that as it stands it is okay. The post is marked as community wiki, there is attribution present (also note that the link to a user's profile with the user id is valid even if the user name changes), it hasn't had much voting so there is not much exposure to it. This case is fine in my opinion. If you find other examples of this, especially from this year or 2015, then they should definitely be thoroughly examined for duplication and probable removal.

Comment: Ok i understand - but just to clarify the link to the user profile was added by my edit. It was not present before. The referenced user `Buzzer` can no longer be matched - based on the answer text it is likely user [tvanfosson](http://stackoverflow.com/users/12950/)

Comment: @slackmuggle - Ah, well good job tracking that down :) However, I think that this is more a super edge case than anything else. If you find new examples of this, make sure to flag them with a custom moderator message explaining your findings.

Comment: You mean *"a very respectable AI construct that escaped from the Australian Defence Department"* -right?

Comment: @TJ - *shhh*, they're listening!