# Closing for duplicate

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

I have a very difficult choice to do and I feel it is too sensitive. I don't want to do it myself...

Duplicate cases:

- [Loop through “selected” Enum values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303353/loop-through-selected-enum-values)
- [Iterate over values in Flags Enum?](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwju0KyxhZbNAhXCeD4KHfeICfQQFggpMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F4171140%2Fiterate-over-values-in-flags-enum&usg=AFQjCNHrBvfE77qJJR8G_hO9B9cUDitfDw&sig2=dvCusqPKSTWfLtZ_w2n0Dg)

One of my answer has been deleted because it was exactly the same answer used for 2 questions. That's true' I don't deny. Questions were duplicate to me, yes. But there is so many valuable information in both questions/answers and both are pretty old too. Closing one would decrease the chances that valuable information would be consulted. Also, the initial one has few votes (5) and the newer one has so many (77). Which one should I close ???

I wonder, if in these controversial cases like that, the admin who deleted an answer (mine) should not also have also the responsibility to also fix the issue by marking an answer as duplicate by himself? That's very nice to inform a user (in fact I really appreciate to know). But I consider that I can't close any of those 2 posts because both are old and both provide valuable information by their many answers/comments. Instead, I answered both. And I think my answer is pretty good, by deleting it, some users could miss it.

My vision is that a merge would be the best, but we can't do it and it would be very complex to implements. What's the best way to fix that kind of sensitive duplicate issue?

Comment: As always the dupe target should be the one with the best answers.

Comment: @NathanOliver, you mean that we should keep the one with best answers? Who can judge that? For new post, it is easy, I close the newer one. But for old ones with lots of answers... I don't want to be the judge.

Comment: You and the other close voters get to judge that.  You pick which one you feel is the better of the two questions and close the other one as a dupe of the one you chose.  If people disagree then they will comment, not vote, vote to leave open(in the queue).

Comment: It seems you're mistaken - the high scoring question is from 2010, the other one from 2012.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions will only be merged if they are really [identical](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312126/4751173); answers won't be changed, so for a merge all answers to question A must make sense as an answer to question B. That is not often the case.

Also, regarding your [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325659/closing-for-duplicate/325662#comment354449_325659):

> For new post, it is easy, I close the newer one. But for old ones with lots of answers... I don't want to be the judge.

It's [no problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252017/4751173) for an older question to be closed as the duplicate of a newer one. Especially in this case, where the newer question and its answers are clearly superior than the older ones (judging by the number of upvotes).

The duplicate question will be closed, but it won't be deleted automatically. The users will keep the reputation gained (or lost) with the question and answers. Also, the question will still be visible in Google searches.

Comment: That's bad. The first one ask the proper question. The second one did not verify properly before asking. Closing the inital one will penalize the wrong one.

Comment: Also, there is valuable answers in initial one. What will happen to them???

Comment: @EricOuellet They will remain unless individually deleted or unless the question which they answer is deleted. Voting on answers to closed questions is still allowed.

Comment: Thanks! I voted to close as duplicate (which I really hate to do) and I left a message to the admin to merge both questions.

Comment: I wonder. Now that the close for duplicate is done. Can I undelete my answer which I think it could be very useful?

Comment: @Glorfindel, But I can click "undelete". It will only flag? Would it be fair to ask for undelete with reasons to justify my move (brings, I think, a potential nice answer)?

Comment: @EricOuellet I'm not sure. However, I'm pretty sure the flag will be declined. In the end, more people will view the original question (and its answers) so it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Glorfindel, Ok thanks.