# How can I fix multiple variations of the same question?

Tags: discussion

My question will be clearer with an example

If one searches for the phrase "makefile:4: *** missing separator. Stop",
one gets many results.

I think the oldest question, *[Make error: missing separator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/920413/7952027)*, has the most answers followed by the second-oldest question, *[makefile:4: *** missing separator. Stop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16931770/7952027)*.

All the rest of the questions like *[Getting error when executing Make File with if condition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52004618/7952027)*, *[Rules of executing shell command in Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52817021/7952027)*, etc. are mostly answered by one of the answers of the older questions.

**Disclaimer**

I too am guilty of asking and self answering questions on this topic *[Makefile:12: *** missing separator. Stop. gfortran](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69837864/7952027)*

Clearly just flagging such questions is not enough, because their rate of production is too high. Must we write a script such that similarly worded questions are sent for review or something on those lines?

I think that at least the two top questions *[Make error: missing separator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/920413/7952027)* and *[makefile:4: *** missing separator. Stop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16931770/7952027)* must be merged.

I know that duplicate closure exists. On closing the question the unique answers to the duplicate question become less discoverable. So I find it difficult to proceed.

Comment: "Clearly just flagging such questions is not enough, because their rate of production is too high." So many of them are asked each day (or even second), that you cannot flag them as duplicates of the duplicate target with the best answer(s)?

Comment: This reads like you did not know that duplicate closure exists since you talk about scripting and merging.

Comment: The only real reason to merge instead of closing as a duplicate is if two similar questions exist and both have distinct, upvoted answers that both should be on the same question. The answers read similar enough to me, so voting to close as duplicates seems fine.

Comment: Are you asking [under what circumstances and/or using what criteria two questions should be merged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312091/what-is-the-correct-procedure-for-requesting-that-two-questions-be-merged)? If that is not what you are asking, please clarify further.

Comment: I just want to make a flow chart such that an objective decision-making process can be established. This would help  determine what has to be done with a question based on its characteristics.

Comment: Re *"Clearly just flagging such questions is not enough, because their rate of production is too high"*: Yes, we can't keep up, but for most users (from search engine hits) it is more important that comments on those questions point towards the canonical questions. Whether they are actually closed is less important (the comments are also important information for those who vote to close).