# Merged Q/A pages instead of "duplicate question" links

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, merged-questions

I've changed this from a feature-request to a discussion, since my ideas weren't (and probably still aren't) well formed enough to constitute a solid proposal. Thanks for pointing me in that direction, @YvetteColomb.

Here's my latest thinking:

1. Currently, when you close a question as a duplicate, those who happen to come to duplicate first get to see the original, but those who come to the original first don't get to see the duplicate. It's not uncommon for a duplicate to actually gain traction and receive good quality answers before it's closed, so it's not ideal that links are only "one-way". A solution to this would be to have "merged Q/A pages", where you present a list of virtually identical questions (with a hint as to their quality) and allow users to sequentially step through each one.

   *Mockup showing two questions merged onto a single Q/A page with second question selected:*

   [image: Mockup of merged Q/A page]

   A nice property of this is that it blurs the lines between what would otherwise be completely separate Q/A's by making it easy to switch between them. I don't claim this is as unified as a true merge (where you end up with just one question and set of answers), but given that no human is required to choose the "better" question and determine whether the answers from the other question are fully compatible, it seems like a good compromise.

---

2. This should perhaps be considered a separate suggestion, since it's not required for #1 to work and is apparently quite controversial, but if a quality question with quality answers is identified as a duplicate of an existing quality question with quality answers, neither should be closed. If we close one in this case, we are essentially choosing the "winner", but we have no real basis for doing this. Both questions should be allowed to live on, however, with the ease of switching between them (thanks to #1 above), this makes it somewhat as if they are one Q/A.
3. This one may already exist (though I haven't been able to find documentation for it), but in the interest of making users (especially new users) feel welcome/included, we should *ask* users before "closing as duplicate" rather than making the decision for them. If users are given a chance to say, "Oh this answer from this other question answers my question", go ahead and close, but if they can adequately explain why none of the existing answers solve their problem, we should *not* close it. However, in either case, we should merge them (as in put them on the same Q/A page).

---

**Original**

Given that Stack Overflow has acknowledged it has an [inclusivity problem](https://twitter.com/balpha/status/984839394829000706), one thing that might help is to improve how duplicates are handled, which currently could be seen as punitive or harsh (even though that's not the intention).

I've had questions closed as duplicates before, and despite understanding the reason for it, I still felt a twinge of shame. (Even that time I voted to close [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120318/nice-clean-cross-join-in-linq-using-only-extension-methods) as a duplicate, it felt somehow unpleasant.) Now imagine if I were a new user and didn't understand the reason for it. I might feel genuinely alienated. When people are made to feel bad enough times, they don't come back.

Besides the inclusivity problem, there are practical problems with the way we currently handle duplicates. What if the older question (the one that doesn't get closed) has no answers that solves your problem? Once the question is closed, no further answers can be added, leaving you with little recourse. Also, I often see newer, duplicate questions that happen to gain more traction (votes, high-quality answers, etc.) than the original, yet the system favors the original.

From [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262495/how-to-merge-duplicate-questions), there is apparently a mechanism for merging questions. However, it requires someone to painstakingly review both question and all the answers to determine whether the answers go with the "better" of the two questions. (I may not have this quite right -- there isn't much information in the help center for this feature.)

The type of merging I have in mind is much simpler. **Just show all duplicates on the same Q/A page, and provide a mechanism to switch between the questions that makes it easy to sequentially step through each one**. This eliminates the need to click through a complex web of links to find the best answer.

[see mockup above]

This opens the door to some interesting features. One that might be particularly useful is the ability to mark the answer to a merged question as the answer to your own question. The system could then "downgrade" the question by removing it from "new, unanswered" question lists (while still allowing an answer to be provided down the road, such as if existing answers become outdated). Features could also be added to better indicate the quality of the duplicate Q/A's (in addition to just *N answers*), so searchers coming to the page could better direct their effort toward the strongest Q/A in the list.

Comment: "The UI of the duplicate system unnecessarily makes question authors feel like they did something wrong" would be a better motivation for this kind of proposal than "Closing posts as exact duplicates is hostile, counter-productive, and one of the reasons Stack Overflow has an inclusivity problem" -- the latter, I believe, overstates your case.

Comment: *What if the older question has no answers that solves your problem?* If the older question doesn't answer your question, then it's not a duplicate and the newer question shouldn't be closed at all. The whole point of closing as duplicate is not to duplicate answers in multiple questions. But if the answers aren't the same there is no need to close.

Comment: But in general, I'm not against "merging" duplicates instead of close-link to a duplicate.

Comment: Clarification: according to your suggestion, would merged questions remain open?

Comment: How do you envision this working with multiple dupe targets for the same question?

Comment: I try to handle the duplicate more gently and that's it: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352439/should-we-add-more-explanation-when-closing-as-duplicate

Comment: Merging implies closing as duplicate and moving all the answers towards the target question and locking the source. Merging is closing as duplicate on vitamins!

Comment: @Braiam As far as this feature request goes, the fourth paragraph (about the counter-productiveness of the duplicate closing) suggests otherwise, though it would be good to have confirmation of that point from devuxer.

Comment: "What if the older question (the one that doesn't get closed) has no answers that solves your problem?" Then the system doesn't allows you to close as duplicate. There's no problem.

Comment: Maybe SO has an inclusitivity problem with users who don't want to be "included" in SO culture, but want their problem solved, _right now_. Who don't want to learn and adapt. Calling closing as duplicate "hostile" doesn't make things better.

Comment: I agree that SO sometimes has a problem with including newbies. But I've never had the feeling that gender/race/etc has an impact on the question. For a majority of users asking questions in my field, I couldn't even tell which gender or race they have.

Comment: @duplode and Modus Tollens, I agree, my tone could have been a lot better. I edited that paragraph to better reflect my thoughts and to hopefully distract less from my UI suggestion.

Comment: @BDL, when I click close, I see "This question has been asked before and already has an answer." It doesn't say, "This question has been asked before and already has at least one high quality answer or accepted answer." Two very different things in my opinion.

Comment: @devuxer: You can only close as duplicate if there is an upvoted or an accepted answer in the target. How else would you measure quality? And as I already said: If the duplicate doesn't solve your problem, then it's not a duplicate. What I'm definitely against is having very similar answers just to tailor them exactly to ops problem. A NullPointerException is a NullPointerException. If you have basic debugging skills one should be able to find out why it happens.

Comment: One thing that I see that I know a lot of new users feel is the 'shame' of a duplicate post.but that is **their** feeling. stack doesn't discourage dupes, so posting one definitely isn't shameful. Why do you feel this way? I personally wouldn't. Maybe that is what needs changing? Whether the perception is correct or not, if it exists, it may be worth fixing?

Comment: @BDL, I just tried to close this question as a duplicate of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366038/should-see-vote-counts-be-available-to-everyone-instead-of-as-a-privilege, which currently has zero answers. The system did nothing to stop me. So, when you say "you can only close as duplicate if there is an upvoted or an accepted answer," you must mean "you *should* only...".

Comment: @devuxer duple closing on meta doesn't require such an answer. Dupe voting on main does (unless both posts are from the same account, if memory serves)

Comment: @Patrice, Ah OK, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Patrice, I agree that SO doesn't intend for anyone to feel shame when they post a duplicate, but I'm quite certain that it does. Even a downvote causes emotions in people. Having your post closed (which you may have worked hard to write) is not a good feeling. As I said in my post, I understand the reason for it, but that doesn't make me feel zero emotions. **I'm not saying we need to try to prevent 100% of bad feelings--that's not realistic or desirable--but if there are things we can do to make SO more welcoming that don't sacrifice the goals of the community, we should.**

Comment: @devuxer oh 100%. I was just saying I wouldn't personally feel this way, so I was trying to zero in on what makes you feel this way to see if it can be tweaked. I don't think merging vs duplicating will help in changing that (not that it wouldn't be a bad change. Just thinking it won't fix that feelings issue)

Comment: @Patrice, I suspect that merging as I defined it (where your question still remains intact and simply gets grouped with another on the same Q/A page) would result in fewer negative emotions. Hard to prove, of course, but that's my strong intuition.

Comment: @Patrice, I also think that if the system *ask* users whether the duplicate answers their question (rather than just coldly closing after 5 votes), that would help a lot. So, if there are five duplicate votes, the user is asked if the proposed duplicate has an answer that solves their problem. If so, it would be a lot more palatable to close their post.

Comment: @devuxer stop me if I am wrong, but when someone votes or flag a question as a supervisor, the OP is offered the chance to review and accept the dupe himself, no? The 5 close voters only come into play if the OP doesn't do this (and considering how many users never come back after asking their Q, this is necessary). I personally don't see how the issue is the closure though. If you are ashamed of not finding the dupe, how is merging vs closing as duplicate change that shame?

Comment: *as a duplicate,not supervisor. Silly autocorrect

Comment: @Patrice, I haven't had this happen in a while, so I'm actually not sure what happens these days. If it works the way you say, that's definitely preferable. As for the shame, there still may be shame, but there isn't the feeling that you were punished for your "wrong-doing". Closing without user consent, to me, is punitive.

Comment: @devuxer sorry if this sounds condescending...but you may want to be100% sure of how the duplicate system works before proposing to rehaul it so much? And while I get your point about not being great to close without the OP's consent.... How do you work with A) users who never come back to their questions? Or B) users who refuse to accept their posts are dupe, because they want a copy pasteable answer instead of understanding what they are doing wrong?

Comment: @devuxer while I like your ideas - perhaps this would be better tagged as a [meta-tag:discussion] rather than a [meta-tag:feature-request]?

Comment: @Patrice, fair point, but I didn't come across that in the help center (https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates), and it hasn't happened to me recently, so it's not easy to be 100% sure how things work. (A) If the user doesn't return within a certain number of days, by all means, closing is reasonable. (B) Then their question should be closed for another reason (e.g., "homework").

Comment: @devuxer but homework isn't a close reason. The question gets closed because it's a dupe, not because it's homework. I do agree getting a precise understanding of the system can be hard. It's likely scattered through a bunch of meta posts.

Comment: @Patrice, Sorry, not "homework" per se. Technically, I would file that under "Unclear what you're asking". If it appears to everyone but the user that it's a duplicate, then that could be an indication that the question is not clear enough. Bottom line: while I do think we should ask the user if their question has already been answered, if the user cannot provide a viable reason why it's not, there should be recourse for moderators to still close the question.

Comment: @devuxer I don't think users will be thinking we are less elitist if we don't dupe-close anymore but unclear-close instead. Isn't that just shifting the problem from one close reason to another? I don't see this changing much in terms of the 'elitist' vision a lot of new users have of Stack. Maybe this could fix how people see duplicates though. Not sure that's enough of a problem by itself it warrants fixing. I guess it depends if you want to fix the perception the community is elitist, or fix how people see duplicates

Comment: @Patrice, I wasn't really targeting elitism. People are always going to be upset by the decisions of the community and moderators, and I don't think we can ever completely avoid that. What we can do is minimize unpleasant surprises. Such as, "Surprise! Your question looks like another question so we're closing it!" Or "Surprise! Your first ever question on this site just generated 3 downvotes with no one even leaving a comment to tell you why!" These are the kinds of things that I think upset and drive people away.

Comment: I think the massive negative votes for your suggestion probably inform you more than any comments or answer will.  Every system worth it's salt which I've used to manage projects (SO is nothing more than a long running knowledge base project) has had some mechanism to merge issues/tickets.  Yet why so much hostility?  This gets at the core of the question  of if there can there be an increase in utility without an equal incease toxicity?  Will be nice to see if/how they can pull their heads out of the sand or whatever place they have them buried.

Comment: @Ray, Yup. I reckon what I experienced with this post is similar to what people experience on the main site. Definitely doesn't make me want to try again.

Comment: To be fair, I've learned in the past few day's a meta downvote is more of a `I don't agree with your proposal`, but not that it's not a valid question to bring up (as downvotes it would signal on main site).   I still don't like that for discussions as I've no idea why they disagree (hence why you want the DISCUSSION).

Comment: @Ray, That's true...I just didn't like the "drive-by" downvotes, where people didn't give any indication why they didn't like the proposal. Then, once I edited/improved the proposal, I don't think many people noticed--or they still disagreed but didn't say anything. In any case, turned out to be a huge waste of time.

Answer (score 2):

On a preliminary note, it is worth reviewing what is the point of duplicate closing. Closing questions as duplicates saves potential answerers the trouble of actually writing an answer; also, it often saves question authors time that would be spent waiting for a good answer to their question to be written. Furthermore, duplicate closing is an important *consolidation* mechanism: from the content curation perspective, the aim is avoiding having lots of redundant, essentially equivalent answers where one good answer (or a handful of them) would be enough.

> I've had questions closed as duplicates before, and despite understanding the reason for it, I still felt a twinge of shame. [...] Now imagine if I were a new user and didn't understand the reason for it. When people are made to feel bad enough times, they don't come back.

There should be no stigma or shame associated with having your question closed as a duplicate. If, in spite of that, people consistently feel bad after running into the duplicate system, we should, before considering throwing away the whole system, look into UI improvements (for a past example, consider the rewording of the duplicate banner -- from "this question is an exact duplicate of" to "this question has an answer here") and behavioural changes that might dispel that. (By the way, writing a couple lines to explain to an OP why a non-obvious duplicate answers their question goes a long way.)

> What if the older question (the one that doesn't get closed) has no answers that solves your problem?

Then the closure was wrong, and shouldn't have happened. Rather than getting rid of duplicate closure, a more measured way of addressing it would be looking for ways to get people to cast better duplicate votes, and to make it easier for question authors to draw attention to questionable closures ([changes aimed at that have also happened](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250981/242059)).

> Also, I often see newer, duplicate questions that happen to gain more traction (votes, high-quality answers, etc.) than the original, yet the system favors the original.

The system doesn't really favour the original. If you identify a pair of duplicates in which and the newer Q&A is better (the answers are better, the question is clearer, etc.), you should close the older question against the newer one. People not doing that consistently is primarily a behavioural issue.

(A related complaint about duplicates is having questions closed against very old questions with outdated answers. Avoiding that would likely involve better mechanisms to keep old Q&As up-to-date, and perhaps tweaks to the duplicate closure guidelines -- again, it shouldn't be necessary to demolish the entire system.)

---

> The type of merging I have in mind is much simpler. **Just show all duplicates on the same Q/A page, and provide a mechanism to switch between the questions that makes it easy to sequentially step through each one**. This eliminates the need to click through a complex web of links to find the best answer.

Even assuming we aren't going to do away with the duplicate system, I do think this might be an interesting UI improvement. It would make browsing through the duplicates easier, which could be helpful in cases in which more than one of the questions happens to have good answers. There would be a few points to address about which questions should be listed (we probably don't want all of the [~7000 NullPointerException duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/218384?lq=1) to be included), but all in all it sounds like a good idea once we place it in a different context.

Comment: *There should be no stigma or shame associated with having your question closed as a duplicate...* I agree that there shouldn't, but I very strongly feel that there is. *The system doesn't really favour the original.* I'd like to know if that's backed up by data, but I'm glad to know that site policy allows for the older/original question to be closed as a duplicate. *it shouldn't be necessary to demolish the entire system* I'm not proposing demolishing the entire system--I'm proposing a different UI for handling duplicates.

Comment: Reading https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250981/242059, I actually really like that. Well, I like what it's hinting at at least, which is, let the *questioner* decide if the older question not only matches their question but also successfully answers it. It's entirely possible that two questions could be identical but that the older answers for whatever reason don't help the questioner. In that case, it would still be nice if the questions could be merged, however, people should be allowed to answer the newer question.

Comment: Perhaps that little proposal I stuck in at the end really is necessary right away: let people check-mark an answer even if it's from one of the merged questions. (edit: this would be a perhaps elegant way to signal that the user no longer needs their question to receive attention)

Comment: @devuxer (1) On "demolishing the entire system", I wrote the answer assuming your proposal entailed leaving merged questions open (in particular, the remarks in the paragraph starting with "Besides the inclusivity problem [...]" seemed, to me, to suggest that). If that is not the case, I probably should adjust my answer accordingly. (2) I see how accepting an answer from a duplicate might be helpful. Working out what it might take to make such an accept mechanism effective might get us to somewhere interesting.

Comment: I guess my proposal needs a bit of unpacking. The most important part to me is the concept of a merged Q/A page, where users can view and sequentially step through the duplicates. I believe this is a better system than one-way links, where depending which answer you come to first, you may not even know there's a duplicate.

Comment: The other part of my proposal is that duplicates should not be closed. Maybe there's more to it than this, but my currently understanding is that the purpose of closing a question is to discourage the community from expending further energy on it. This should still be the goal, but is closing the only way? If the questioner is satisfied his question has been answered and check-marks the answer, the question should be removed from "new unanswered questions" lists, which would naturally solve the problem without the need to close the duplicate.

Comment: To me, closing still makes sense for low quality questions or questions that are not appropriate for SO, but it doesn't make sense for a duplicate where one version of that question is not better than another simply because it happened to be asked first. I also don't see a need to outright *prevent* someone from coming along (perhaps months or years later) and adding a new answer (which could happen if the old answers are out of date).

Comment: I just significantly updated my proposal/question with a new title and new content.

Comment: @devuxer [1/2] (1) I believe your proposals -- specially the first one, which, on its own, is less likely to cause controversy -- would benefit from being separated from each other. (2) On the second proposal: "[not] expending further energy" is a writer-oriented motivation for duplicate closing; however, there is also consolidation, which should help both readers (ideally it would mean there is less to trawl through before getting to a good answer) and writers (it also would mean less posts to maintain, moderate, and keep updated).

Comment: @devuxer [2/2] The question you put forward -- "is closing the only way?" -- could be asked about consolidation as well. Adding the duplicate banner without closing the question would certainly count as a form of consolidation; what would be left to figure out is whether it would be enough consolidation. As for late answers to duplicate questions, one issue is that often there really isn't anything new to add (for a similar situation, consider the issue of questionable late answers to old, popular questions), though I can think of situations in which it would be a net gain to allow them.

Comment: @devuxer On a different issue: "I'd like to know if [that the system doesn't favour the original] is backed up by data" -- [This SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/839763/ratio-of-duplicates-with-newer-targets) tells us that ~2.5% of questions closed as duplicates have targets older than themselves. The figure grows to ~14.6% if you only consider questions closed a week or more after being posted, which doesn't seem that bad of a ratio.

Comment: I take your point that closing helps consolidation, and I could persuaded that there probably are a number of cases where closing makes sense (e.g., the "null pointer exception" example), but I would still suggest that closing not be the automatic/only solution for duplicates. Here are two cases where closing should not occur (though merging still should): (1) you ask a new question and do *not* feel that one of the existing answers solves your problem and (2) two or more duplicates are of high quality and have several viable answers.

Comment: @devuxer (1/2) About your examples: (1) Then op should update their question to
reflect why the duplicate didn't solve their problem. I bet 90% of the time op just hasn't
understood what the actual problem is and why the duplicate solves it. Now tailoring the answer to
ops problem is not what SO is for. We are not here to help each and every user with their personal problem.
SO should be a library for high-quality content that can be found by many people. Tailoring answers to specific situations is usually just noise and
prevents people from finding the general explanation.

Comment: (2/2): (2) Duplicate closing is not restricted to linking to one question. There can also be multiple duplicate targets.
But if there exist multiple questions with high-quality answers to the same problem, then duplicate closing has
failed in the first place. There should never be two high-quality questions about the same problem that aren't duplicate
closed.
From reading your comments I more and more believe that what actually drives your feature-request is that you want
custom tailored answers to duplicates which, in my opinion, is a bad idea.

Comment: @BDL, SO should not become a repository of obscure answers to obscure questions. I'm simply stating that just because two *questions* are duplicates, it doesn't mean the old answers solve the new problem. The primary example that comes to mind is that the answers could be outdated or version dependent. Another possibility is that two users are getting the same error message, but a solution that works for one user doesn't work for another due to configuration. In this latter case, you could argue it's not really a duplicate, but it would be so close, merging would still make sense.

Comment: As I already said: A duplicate is only a duplicate if all answers to the target are valid answers for the closed question and if they solve the problem. If it doesn't solve the problem, then the question should not be closed as duplicate. If the problem is for a specific version: State that and explain why the answers in the duplicate don't work for your. Then the question can be reopened if already closed.

Comment: @BDL, I think we're in agreement on the principles, but the way the site works (or at least has worked in the past), is that you post something, five people vote it as a duplicate, then the onus is on you to say, "Hey wait a second, this is not a duplicate!" What I'd like to see is a system that says, "Hey, your question is almost identical to this other question. Does this other question have an answer that helps you?" If the user check-marks that answer, great, glad we could help. If not, let new answers be written.

Comment: I like the suggest of loosing the whole "This is a duplicate, go away plebeian and ask no more".  Maybe simple rebranding can solve the stigma.